# Disable "a script is opening a connection to system: **** ", not via the SAP GUI option

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I have a VBA code which helps to login into SAP GUI. The code works fine but I am getting a warning popup when it establishes the connection.

> A script is opening a connection to system: *******
>
> [image]

I need to either bypass or disable this warning popup. I have written the code but it is not working. Please help.

```
Sub code1()
If Not IsObject(SAPguiApp) Then
    Set SAPguiApp = CreateObject("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")
End If

If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
    Set Connection = SAPguiApp.OpenConnection("********", True)
End If

If Not IsObject(Session) Then
    Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If Session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
    If Session.findbyid("wnd[1]").Text Like "A script*" Then Session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/btnSPOP-OPTION1").press
End If

Session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").Text = "103"
Session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = "*****"
Session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").SetFocus
Session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").caretPosition = 2
Session.findbyid("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

Session.findbyid("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nsu01"
Session.findbyid("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
Session.findbyid("wnd[0]").maximize

End Sub
```

Please note that this popup can be disabled in SAP GUI but I'm not in favour of doing the same because it can lead to a security threat in the future.

Consequently, please advise something to do with the help of a code like below :

```
If Session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
    If Session.findbyid("wnd[1]").Text Like "A script*" Then
        Session.findbyid("wnd[0]/usr/btnSPOP-OPTION1").press
    End If
End If
```

Comment: That warning is popped by SAP client to alert the computer user that some potentially bad script is acting on their behalf. I don't believe there is a way to disable it as that would be circumventing the security put in place by the SAP client to alert the user.

Answer (score 6):

These are settings in the registry which you can turn off and turn on like you want
I have a class clsSapgui for that

```
Option Explicit
Const mRegNameBase = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAP\SAPGUI Front\SAP Frontend Server\Security\"
Const mUserScripting = "UserScripting"
Const mWarnOnAttach = "WarnOnAttach"
Const mWarnOnConnection = "WarnOnConnection"
Const mSecurityLevel = "SecurityLevel"
Dim mRegKey As New clsRegistry

Property Get UserScripting() As Boolean
    UserScripting = ReadRegKey(mUserScripting)
End Property

Property Let UserScripting(newVal As Boolean)
    WriteRegKey mUserScripting, CBoolToVal(newVal)
End Property

Property Get WarnOnAttach() As Boolean
    WarnOnAttach = ReadRegKey(mWarnOnAttach)
End Property

Property Let WarnOnAttach(newVal As Boolean)
    WriteRegKey mWarnOnAttach, CBoolToVal(newVal)
End Property

Property Get WarnOnConnection() As Boolean
    WarnOnConnection = ReadRegKey(mWarnOnConnection)
End Property

Property Let WarnOnConnection(newVal As Boolean)
    WriteRegKey mWarnOnConnection, CBoolToVal(newVal)
End Property
Property Get SecurityLevel() As Boolean
    SecurityLevel = ReadRegKey(mSecurityLevel)
End Property

Property Let SecurityLevel(newVal As Boolean)
    WriteRegKey mSecurityLevel, CBoolToVal(newVal)
End Property
Private Function CBoolToVal(bVal As Boolean) As Byte
    If bVal Then
        CBoolToVal = 1
    Else
        CBoolToVal = 0
    End If
End Function

Private Function ReadRegKey(sRegValue As String) As String

    Dim sRegName As String

On Error GoTo NoRegkey

    sRegName = mRegNameBase & sRegValue
    ReadRegKey = mRegKey.ReadRegKey(sRegName)
    Exit Function

NoRegkey:
    ReadRegKey = 0

End Function

Private Function WriteRegKey(sRegKey As String, ByVal sRegValue As String) As Boolean

    Dim sRegName As String

On Error GoTo NoRegkey

    sRegName = mRegNameBase & sRegKey
    WriteRegKey = mRegKey.WriteRegKey(sRegName, sRegValue, "REG_DWORD")
    Exit Function

NoRegkey:
    WriteRegKey = False

End Function
```

And then you can turn off the warnings completely

```
Sub Silence()

    Dim mySapGui As New clsSapGui

    With mySapGui
        .UserScripting = True
        .SecurityLevel = False
        .WarnOnAttach = False
        .WarnOnConnection = False
    End With

End Sub
```

And you turn them on again with

```
    Sub Show_Warnings()

        Dim mySapGui As New clsSapGui

        With mySapGui
            .UserScripting = True
            .SecurityLevel = True
            .WarnOnAttach = True
            .WarnOnConnection = True
        End With

End Sub
```

If you want to you can of course add new methods to the class which would be neater

The class clsRegistry looks like that

```
Option Explicit

Function ReadRegKey(RegKey As String) As Variant

Dim wsh As Object

    Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    On Error GoTo NoRegkey

    ReadRegKey = wsh.regread(RegKey)

    Set wsh = Nothing
    Exit Function

NoRegkey:
    ReadRegKey = ""

End Function

Function DeleteRegKey(RegKey As String) As Boolean
' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfdfhz1b(v=vs.84).aspx
Dim wsh As Object

   Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

   On Error GoTo NoRegkey

   wsh.RegDelete RegKey
   DeleteRegKey = True
   Set wsh = Nothing
   Exit Function

NoRegkey:
    DeleteRegKey = False

End Function


Function WriteRegKey(RegName As String, RegValue As Variant, RegType As String) As Boolean
' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfdfhz1b(v=vs.84).aspx
Dim wsh As Object

   Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

   On Error GoTo NoRegkey

   wsh.RegWrite RegName, RegValue, RegType
   WriteRegKey = True
   Set wsh = Nothing
   Exit Function

NoRegkey:
    WriteRegKey = False

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

the setting **is in the SAP GUI**. Under the **security folder**.

[image: SAP Gui Screenshot]

https://blogs.sap.com/2015/06/09/tips-stop-the-pop-up-sap-gui-security-remeber-my-decision/

Comment: That's pretty handy. Perhaps OP can script to toggle that so the user only has to hit the button once. Although, I would caution them from doing so since it's programatically shutting off a security feature for the user which may invite nefarious scripts to act without prompt in the future.

Comment: I agree, is a pain but I see why this feature is there. Yes please use with caution.

Comment: -1. The question is not related to the "Security" settings, it's related to the "Accessibility & Scripting > **Scripting**" settings of the same SAP GUI Options.

Answer (score 1):

Let me complete the answer given by Storax concerning the SAP GUI entries in the Windows Registry in words rather than code only.

Storax answer corresponds to setting to off/unticking the checkboxes the below two SAP GUI Options by script, then restore their previous values:

[image]

[image: SAP GUI Options > Accessibility & Scripting > Scripting]

Official description from the guide "SAP GUI Administration - Document Version: 7.70 PL03 – 2021-06-16" (https://help.sap.com/doc/6ceeb0cbf06540d18c116f060f0669aa/770.03/en-US/sap_gui_administration.pdf):

> ***Notify when a script attaches to SAP GUI***
>
> - *[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAP\SAPGUI Front\SAP Frontend Server\Security]*
> - *WarnOnAttach` (REG_DWORD) [Default: 1] {0 = inactive; 1 = active}*
>
> ***Notify when a script opens a connection***
>
> - *[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAP\SAPGUI Front\SAP Frontend Server\Security]*
> - *WarnOnConnection (REG_DWORD) [Default: 1] {0 = inactive; 1 = active}*

Windows Registry (`regedit.exe`):

[image: SAP GUI Options Windows Registry]