# Disable a script is attempting to access SAP GUI, not via the SAP GUI option

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

Is there any other way to disable "A Script is Attempting to Access SAP GUI" by using Excel VBA instead of disable in Accessibility & Scripting setting in SAP GUI?

I mean like whenever the popup appear, the script from VBA will always click OK button.

[image]

Comment: Why would you do to want that? You can turn off the popup appearing by modifying some settings in the registry. The base key is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAP\SAPGUI Front\SAP Frontend Server\Security`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53769018/6600940

Comment: @Storax the main reason why because some user they still don't know and don't want to follow the instruction to "disable in Accessibility & Scripting setting in SAP GUI". It is very hard to educate all of the user, so if there any solution to bypass straight away the notification "A Script is Attempting to Access SAP GUI" directly without going to setting in SAP, it will be really helpful.

Comment: @sepiroth: If you take a look at the linked post, you'll notice that it's possible to suppress the warnings you mentioned using VBA. There's no need to instruct users on how to do it themselves; you can simply employ VBA for this purpose

Comment: Hi @SandraRossi and Storax, finally I found the solution for the issue which is from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71209992/sap-gui-script-from-excel-vba-macro-optimizing, I believe it's similar to Storax mentioned, just need to change few lines and now it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip automatically popup "A script is attempting to access SAP GUI" and "A script is opening a connection to system: \*\*\*\*\*\*\*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71209992/how-to-skip-automatically-popup-a-script-is-attempting-to-access-sap-gui-and)

Comment: @SandraRossi Yes the link answered my question, now it worked according to what i need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since this popup is not a SAP GUI window it can not be accessed by the scripting engine (wich would make no sense, since its purpose is to surpress scripts as long as the user has not approved to run it).

Maby with this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289777/how-can-i-send-keyboard-commands-hold-release-simultanous-with-a-python-script) (wich is for python, I don't know something like this for vba) you can figure out how to send a  keystroke to the popup but this is not stable nor adviable behavior for a script.

If you want to run scripts without warning then disable the warning.

Comment: Please [add some context about the link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise the answer may have no interest for future visitors if the external hyperlink disappears.​

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm off topic, but although you want a programmatic solution "instead of disable in Accessibility & Scripting setting in SAP GUI", probably many people will come to your question to disable manually this setting.

Here it is:

1. SAP Logon pad > Menu Options

   [image: SAP GUI Options menu]
2. Options > Accessibility & Scripting > Scripting > Enable scripting > **Notify when a script attaches to SAP GUI**

   [image: SAP GUI Options Accessibility Scripting Notify when a script attaches to SAP GUI]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53769018/6600940

Comment: @storax you'd better post an answer with a link to your answer in the other question you mention (whose question is slightly different from this one i.e. about the other notify option, but your answer solves both).

Comment: @storax and for sure, I will vote for it ;-)

Comment: _@Sandra Rossi_ I believe my response to the previous question should offer enough information for the original poster to adapt it effectively to their specific issue. However, if they prefer to pursue the button-clicking approach, it would entail utilizing API calls and similar methods, which, in my opinion, could be rather cumbersome in this particular scenario.

Comment: Your response was one made for the other question, not for this question, and they are both different questions. You consider it's the same question because they refer to very close functional cases, and your answer on the other question grouped 2 answers in one. You can vote to close this question if you think it's a duplicate question.

Comment: My response to the other question was geared towards modifying registry settings, the original poster's query specifically involves clicking the OK button. My response actually addresses a completely different approach. To accomplish using API calls, the OP would need to work with API calls, a topic I'm not inclined to delve into.

Comment: @storax In the end, you can see that the OP is fine with modifying registry settings.

Comment: Certainly! It appears that the OP is comfortable with making modifications to the registry settings. This has already been discussed and explained in another post and I even mention that in the accepted answer of the post you linked to. So, fine with me. Let's hope the OP comprehends what the code is about. Because, I guess, they won't even undo the settings.